# How can I connect a 4mm Stepper motor shaft to a technic gear?

Tags: technic, motor, gears, 3rd-party, connections

How can I connect a 4mm or 6mm stepper motor D shaft to an old Technic gear?

I would like to mount an old 8-tooth gear to a 4-6 mm diameter stepper motor shaft.

Lego part: [3647](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3647#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):

[image: 3647]

[Stepper motor](https://www.pololu.com/product/2256):

[image: Electric motor]

Potential solution found on 3[D Printing StackExchange](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/19522/stepper-motor-d-shaft-to-lego-axle-adapter).

Working solution:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I did find this pattern for a 3-D printer.

https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-print-models/hobby-diy/mechanical-parts/6mm-dshaft-to-lego-axis-adapter

Answer (score 4):

For 6 mm shaft the hole used to accept LEGO Technic axle is slightly less in diameter than 6 mm. So you may try modifying one end of of Technic connectors (some examples below) to fit the motor shaft and use usual Technic axle on the other end of connector.

[6538c - Technic, Axle Connector 2L (Smooth with x Hole + Orientation)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6538c#T=C)

[image]

[6538b - Technic, Axle Connector 2L (Ridged with x Hole x Orientation)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6538b#T=C)

[image]